# How to persist webview cookies between app executions?

Tags: android, cookies, webview, android-webview, android-cookiemanager

It is possible to achieve this currently in Android? I only can find deprecated questions about old methods (CookieSynchManager) which not seems to work for this actually.

It is possible to achieve it? I can't find anything also on the Android Developers' Guide.

Answer (score 10):

Having the same problem...I solved reading the doc here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieSyncManager

For future readers: to force the Cookie sync process you can manually call the flush() method of CookieManager

I personally put in webview the following code:

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
      CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
      CookieManager.getInstance().acceptCookie();
      CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: After looking at numerous other answers that didn't work for me, this was the one that finally did. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since **CookieSynchManager** is deprecated, *CookieManager.getInstance()* is the **CookieManager** instance for your entire application.  Hence, you enable it by

```
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true)
```

> setAcceptCookie(boolean accept);
>
> Sets whether the application's WebView instances should send and
>   accept cookies.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html

Comment: Hi, but these cookies are stored on RAM or will persist?

Comment: @NullPointerException It will persist unless the data/cache is cleared from App Info. Or in other case if we want to clear the cookies, we can clear it programatically.

Comment: @Manoj_Frekzz thank you but where can you find it? can't I find that description on the documentation

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html