# how to save google login session android webView?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

i have an android app with a webView to open some youtube links but i have a problem that every time the app close and reopen i need to login again i read some questions here but didn't got an answer this is my code.

```
webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    String url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+vidInfo[vidNum][2];
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAppCachePath(getCacheDir().getPath());
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your session data is saved in cookies. you therefore need to make them persistent between sessions
[checkout this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45751626/how-to-persist-webview-cookies-between-app-executions)